# Mask number to hash format in angular 2+

Tags: angular

Need to mask input value to following format while user types:

lets say user is typing 123451234512345123451234512345123 then the value should be shown as ###.#####.####.######.######.####.##### while typing itself and the actual model should always contain the original value that user entered

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: There is a popular NPM package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-mask-addons
using that can save lots of time and effort

Answer (score 0):

One way to do achieve that is to create directive with proper @HostListener.

Example here:
[Phone mask directive example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask?file=app%2Fphone-mask.directive.ts)

In example there is listener to ngModelChange and event when you click backspace button. The only thing you need to do is to customize that function :

```
onInputChange(event, backspace) {}
```

Let me know when you need more help.